# Python - dataframe insert error "TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to insert a row in the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
earnings_dates_returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock_name','Announcement_date'])
earnings_dates_returns.insert(0, {'Stock_name': 'Apple', 'Announcement_date': '2010-01-01'})
```

but I am getting this error:

> TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Why do I get it? How can I fix it?

Comment: The docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), say "Insert column into DataFrame at specified location", not row. To insert a row, use "append" like in jezrael's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with `Series` if is necessary specify index value.

If need `append` in loop it is possible, but slow:

```
earnings_dates_returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock_name','Announcement_date'])
s = pd.Series({'Stock_name': 'Apple', 'Announcement_date': '2010-01-01'}, name=0)
earnings_dates_returns = earnings_dates_returns.append(s)
print (earnings_dates_returns)
  Stock_name Announcement_date
0      Apple        2010-01-01

s = pd.Series({'Stock_name': 'Pear', 'Announcement_date': '2011-01-01'}, name=5)
earnings_dates_returns = earnings_dates_returns.append(s)
print (earnings_dates_returns)
  Stock_name Announcement_date
0      Apple        2010-01-01
5       Pear        2011-01-01
```

> Does it work if I add more than one rows in the dataframe?

I think better is create list of dicts or Series first and then create `DataFrame` for improve performance:

```
out = []
for data in iterator:
    #some processing if necessary
    out.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: I think your post is missing the `earnings_dates_returns = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Stock_name','Announcement_date'])` but other than that it works fine thanks! Accepted!

Comment: What does name=0 mean?

Comment: @adrCoder - it is for new index name, if not interesting use `earnings_dates_returns = earnings_dates_returns.append(s, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Does it work if I add more than one rows in the dataframe?

Comment: If I add data in some columns, then how can I add more data in other columns of the same entry?

Comment: @adrCoder - If use `Series` with name by existing index - e.g. if need overwite/add new columns for index 5, then use `s = pd.Series({'Stock_name': 'Apple', 'Announcement_date': '2010-01-01'}, name=5)`

Comment: How can I find the index if I don't know it?

Comment: @adrCoder - hmmm, I need more information. `If I add data in some columns, then how can I add more data in other columns of the same entry?` - do you think DataFrame has some rows, columns and need new row? Or need e.g. add new columns/row for first row. Not sure if understand, the best should be some data sample/expected output.